# Recall and precision point estimates (statistical inference)

Tags: precision-recall, point-estimation

Let's say I have a population of 1M objects. I want to make a binary classifier to use on that data, but I can't manually classify all the 1M to create training data because that would take too long, so I:

1. Take a small sample of that population
2. Lable that sample manually
3. Train a classifier

Calculating the model's recall and precision on my training data is easy enough. However, how do I estimate the recall and precision on the whole **population** ?

My instincts want to say that the sample's precision/recall is a good estimator (point estimator) for the population's precision/recall, but is it really?

I'd really appreciate references about this topic so I can look into.